# How safe is this method of login in Flask python

Tags: python, authentication, flask

I wanted to have site protected by password, different site for each user.

```
LOGIN_HASH = {
    "admin": str(hash("admin")),
    "user": str(hash("user"))
}

USERS = {
    "user1": [hash("pw1"), "page_admin"],
    "user2": [hash("pw2"), "page_user"]
}


@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def page_login():
    if request.method == "POST":
        login = request.form["login"]
        password = hash(request.form["password"])
        if login in USERS:
            if USERS[login][0] == password:
                return redirect(url_for(USERS[login][1]))
        return render_template("page_login.html")
    return render_template("page_login.html")


@app.route(f"/lab/admin-{LOGIN_HASH['admin']}")
def page_admin():
    return "admin"


@app.route(f"/lab/user-{LOGIN_HASH['user']}")
def page_user():
    return "user"
```

I'm not using this for anything very sensitive, but I don't want average user to access admin page. I know that you can access that page by typing URL from web history, but I don't plan to login to admin page from user computer. In such case, I think I can reload website and adress will change, as hash() gives different output each time.
Is this method of login safe enough?

Comment: This is security by obscurity. The page is only protected by having a random URL.

Comment: No, this implementation wouldn't be considered secure. There's probably no reason to do this, either, since it is simple to just implement proper authentication and authorization.

Comment: This also won't work like you expect – if you use `hash()`, the URLs will change every time you restart your Python application due to hash seed randomization.

Answer (score 3):

No, this wouldn't be considered secure. Just implement proper authentication and authorization instead. If you really still want the view to be random, just generate it randomly, but using proper authentication and authorization is still required to be 'secure'

The [flask-login](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) extension implements a lot of the boilerplate for this for you, making it a lot simpler with a lot more functionality.

Some other notes:

- You probably don't want to use `hash` which is (1) not consistent, meaning users passwords change every reload and (2) is not secure in terms of cryptography.
- You probably should store *salted and hashed* passwords, for example, using [bcrypt](https://github.com/pyca/bcrypt/) or otherwise use a strong hashing algorithm.

Here, I'll provide an example using the standard lib `hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac`. You can also consider other strong password hashing algorithms like [hashlib.scrypt](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html#hashlib.scrypt). But be aware, we're still taking some shortcuts here.

For example, generate the salted and hashed password:

```
import hashlib
import secrets


username = salt = b'user1'
# generating and storing a random salt for each user would be more secure, too.
# salt = secrets.token_bytes(32)  # store this value somewhere

# generate a random password
# password = bytes(secrets.token_urlsafe(32), 'ascii')
password = b'pw1'  # static for this example
print(username, 'keep this safe:', str(password, 'ascii'))

salted_hashed = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac('sha256', password, salt, iterations=500_000)
print('here is the hash', salted_hashed.hex())
```

This will produce an output like:

```
admin keep this safe: pw1
here is the hash aeca87e94befc6006398c776707e39cf79530500b273c3789661dbfcf2e86ffa
```

Then your app can store the salted & hashed password. Usually, this happens in a database, but for simplicity, we'll keep your dictionary approach.

Putting that all together, your app may look like this (without using `flask-login`):

```py
import functools
import hashlib
from flask import session, Flask, request, flash, render_template, redirect, url_for
app = Flask(__name__)


USERS = {
    "user1": ['aeca87e94befc6006398c776707e39cf79530500b273c3789661dbfcf2e86ffa', "page_admin"],
    # ...
}

app.secret_key = b'super-secret'

def login_required(allowed_users='all'):
    def wrapper(view):
        @functools.wraps(view)
        def wrapped_view(*args, **kwargs):
            logged_in_user = session.get('user')
            if logged_in_user is None:
                print('authentication required')
                flash('authentication required')
                return redirect(url_for('page_login'))
            if allowed_users != 'all':
                if logged_in_user not in allowed_users:
                    return 'Not authorized', 403
                else:
                    return view(*args, **kwargs)
            else:  # if allowed_users not specified, any logged in user is OK
                return view(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapped_view
    return wrapper


@app.route('/login', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def page_login():
    if request.method == "POST":
        login = request.form["login"]
        if login in USERS:
            salt = bytes(login, 'ascii')
            pw = bytes(request.form['password'], 'ascii')
            password = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac('sha256', pw, salt, iterations=500_000).hex()
            if password == USERS[login][0]:
                print('Successfully logged in')
                flash('successfully logged in')
                session['user'] = login
                landing_page = USERS[login][1]
                return redirect(url_for(landing_page))
            else:
                print('bad password')
                flash('bad login')
        else:
            print('unknown user')
            flash('bad login')
    return render_template("page_login.html")


@app.route('/lab/user')
@login_required()
def page_user():
    username = session.get('user')
    return f'Hello {username} (user)'

@app.route('/lab/admin')
@login_required(allowed_users=('user1',))
def page_admin():
    username = session.get('user')
    return f'Hello {username} (admin)'
```

Comment: Yes, but **DO NOT** use SHA2 for passwords. Use [BCrypt](https://pypi.org/project/bcrypt/).

Comment: @tadman yeah, bcrypt would be more secure against brute force attacks, true. I'll update the answer. If attackers know or guess your salting method, that can be particularly problematic, too. bcrypt just offers stronger algorithms that are computationally more expensive to brute force and provides some tools for salting, but the principle is the same and the goal here is simplicity (and demonstrable with the standard lib).

Comment: I get that simplicity is a factor, but it's casually given advice like this that takes root in applications as huge vulnerabilities. SHA2 is useless for passwords, and BCrypt isn't hard to use. If there's a Python auth framework that already does this, even better.

Comment: @tadman I suppose. I've updated the answer again to not use sha256

Comment: Not sure that `hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac('sha256',...)` is "not sha256". Hashing with manual salting was proven to be a bad idea in the early 2000s. BCrypt will do that for you.

Comment: @tadman pbkdf2_hmac-sha256 with enough iterations [meets modern security requirements](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/3959). LastPass, for example, uses this.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Unfortunatelly I am getting an error: AttributeError: 'Request' object has no attribute 'session'. How can I resolve this?

Comment: @LOR3MI sorry, my mistake. It should be `session` (imported from `flask`) rather than `request.session`. I'm getting my wires crossed with django. I'll update this.

Comment: @sytech LastPass, which has been breached *multiple times*, is hardly a trusted authority here. BCrypt, please, it's not hard!

Comment: Getting your database of salted/hashed passwords stolen is the first step in the attack. Using bcrypt doesn't prevent that. Decrypting the salted and hashed passwords is the important part -- which has never been accomplished on encrypted lastpass passwords @tadman -- I don't think the distinction is particularly important here.

Comment: Obviously [people have tried to crack them](https://hashcat.net/forum/thread-4446-post-25325.html) and they're finding it's easier than LastPass claims. The point of BCrypt is that it is *painfully* slow if used with defaults, and can be made even more painful if required. It's tens of guesses per second, not thousands or millions, or even trillions as bare SHA2 is like. I'm not busting on you in particular here, but little mistakes like using SHA2 "for now fix later" is how passwords get leaked.

Comment: @sytech Thank you! Unfortunately I have one more problem, I used incognito and tried to access admin page. I've got "Hello None (admin)". It looks like wrapped_view() in decorator isn't executed, but I don't know why.

Comment: @tadman this doesn't use bare SHA256. It still uses the pbkdf2 key derivation algorithm, **the same as bcrypt uses**, but uses sha256-hmac hashing. With 500,000 iterations of sha256-hmac, the hashing rate is 20% slower than bcrypt's default of 32 iterations of bcrypt in my own testing -- keeping in mind, each iteration increases the cracking difficulty exponentially, to the power of the number of bits of entropy. The cost of a dictionary attack is between `2^t` (min) and `C*2^t` (max) where `C` is the number of iterations and `t` is the bits of entropy.

Comment: @LOR3MI I've fixed some errors and updated the answer to provide a complete reproducible solution.